# Website configured in Nginx returns 404 error

Tags: nginx

I have a Amazon EC2 machine using Nginx. I have MediaWiki running and I would like to use Phabricator (another application) on the same server.

My configuration file for Phabricator is:

```
server {
  server_name phabricator.example.com;
  root        /var/www/phabricator;

  location / {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?__path__=/$1 last;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    try_files $uri =204;
  }

  location /index.php {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;

    #required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
    fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

    #variables to make the $_SERVER populate in PHP
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

When I try to use the subdomain configured on `server_name` it shows an 404 page. Other questions on serverfault says that it is causes by an `SCRIPT_FILENAME` misconfig, but it seems to be the way it should be.

Error shown in the log: 
`2015/12/14 13:23:47 [error] 15588#0: *18 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.162.212.95, server: starscream.athoscastro.org, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:`

Comment: What is the message in error logs?.

Comment: @serverliving.com updated (nice username)

Comment: It seems to be saying that `/var/www/phabricator/index.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: or invalid access rights

Comment: derp, I missed the folder the index.php actually is (`webroot`)